# NodeJS module - populated arrays turning into empty objects. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have a module which exports a config object:

```
module.exports = {
    music : {
        catalog : {
            mysql : {
                requiredFields : {
                    foo : [1,2,3],
                    trackQuery : [
                        {
                            table : 'tracks',
                            alias : 't',
                            foo   : [1,2,3],
                            fields : [
                                'id',
                                'name',
                                'duration'
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            table : 'artists',
                            alias : 'a',
                            fields : [
                                'id',
                                'name'
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `fields` arrays are turning into empty objects at runtime.

**I'm confirming like this**:

```
var conf = require('musicConfig');
console.log ("requiredFields = %j", conf.music.catalog.mysql.requiredFields);
```

...**which outputs this**:

```
requiredFields = ["foo":[1,2,3],"trackQuery":[{"table":"tracks","alias":"t","foo":{},"fields":{}},{"table":"artists","alias":"a","fields":{}}]]
```

As you can see:

```
conf.music.catalog.mysql.requiredFields.foo                 // [1,2,3]
conf.music.catalog.mysql.requiredFields.trackQuery[0].foo   // {}  <-- WTF
conf.music.catalog.mysql.requiredFields.trackQuery[0].table // "tracks"
```

Any idea what's going on? Yes, I can move the `fields` array to a higher level namespace and it will work - one step up actually. If I put it directly under `requiredFields` it will stay populated, but that's not an ideal solution.

I've [confirmed here](http://jsfiddle.net/7TgJj/) that it's not an ECMAScript bug and it's not my object structure, because it works as expected.

I'm running Node **0.10.3** on Ubuntu with these dependencies:

```
"dependencies" : {
    "express"    : "3.1.0",
    "redis"      : "0.8.2",
    "jade"       : "0.28.2",
    "mysql"      : "2.0.0-alpha7",
    "mongodb"    : "*",
    "config"     : "0.4.22"
}
```

I thought it might be that [config module](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config), but even when I bypass it the issue remains.

#### UPDATE

Here is the output from: `console.log(util.inspect(config.music.catalog.mysql.requiredFields.trackQuery[0], { showHidden: true, depth: null }));`
 -- though it doesn't really help much. I'm looking into more helpful flags, open to suggestions.

```
{ table: [Getter/Setter],
  alias: [Getter/Setter],
  foo: [Getter/Setter],
  fields: [Getter/Setter],
  [__watchers]:
   { table:
      [ { [Function]
          [length]: 0,
          [name]: '',
          [arguments]: null,
          [caller]: null,
          [prototype]: { [constructor]: [Circular] } },
        [length]: 1 ],
     alias:
      [ { [Function]
          [length]: 0,
          [name]: '',
          [arguments]: null,
          [caller]: null,
          [prototype]: { [constructor]: [Circular] } },
        [length]: 1 ],
     foo:
      [ { [Function]
          [length]: 0,
          [name]: '',
          [arguments]: null,
          [caller]: null,
          [prototype]: { [constructor]: [Circular] } },
        [length]: 1 ],
     fields:
      [ { [Function]
          [length]: 0,
          [name]: '',
          [arguments]: null,
          [caller]: null,
          [prototype]: { [constructor]: [Circular] } },
        [length]: 1 ] },
  [__propertyValues]:
   { table: [ 'tracks', [length]: 1 ],
     alias: [ 't', [length]: 1 ],
     foo: [ { [__watchers]: {}, [__propertyValues]: {} }, [length]: 1 ],
     fields: [ { [__watchers]: {}, [__propertyValues]: {} }, [length]: 1 ] } }
```

Comment: You can require() plain json files in node.js

Comment: You sure it's not just a display bug? Have you actually tried an index, like `...foo[1]`? Is this your actual data, or did you change it in any way before posting?

Comment: ...and you say you can move `fields` to a higher namespace and it'll work... but you're asking about `foo`...

Comment: ...and the default depth limit default is `2`, so as I suggested a couple comments up, it's probably a display issue. To view the data to a full depth, use [`util.inspect()`](http://www.nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):  `console.log(util.inspect(conf.music.catalog.mysql.requiredFields, {depth: null}));`

Comment: It flagged my `fields.length === 0` exception, and when I tried referencing `fields[0]` it was `undefined`

Comment: Also, I only created `foo` to rule out the name `fields` being the culprit. Either array at a higher namespace level will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problems when the file is read using the `config` module, so I don't think you're bypassing it correctly.

Also, when I increase `DEFAULT_CLONE_DEPTH` in `config/lib/config.js` (it doesn't seem to be configurable from the outside, but I'm not very familiar with it), it works:

```
> console.log(conf.music.catalog.mysql.requiredFields.trackQuery[0].foo)
[ [Getter/Setter], [Getter/Setter], [Getter/Setter] ]
```

Comment: I had bypassed it (so I thought) by `require('./config/default.js')` - changing the clone depth fixed the issue for me. Thank you!!